# VB.net string join, adds unneeded space

Tags: vb.net, string, catia

Having some issues in vb.net string to join two strings together for output to a  txt document. My text document is getting an extra space between the two strings I join. This should not be happening.

```
           If System.IO.File.Exists(path) = True Then
        ' Create a file to write to. 
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(path)
        sw.WriteLine("Attribute VB_Name = " & Chr(34) & "KbTest" & Chr(34))
        sw.WriteLine("")
        sw.WriteLine("Public Sub DoKbTest()")
        sw.WriteLine("'code here")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim catia")
        sw.WriteLine("set catia = GetObject(, " & Chr(34) & "CATIA.Application" & Chr(34) & ")")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim partDocument1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set partDocument1 = catia.ActiveDocument")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim part1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set part1 = partDocument1.Part")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim hybridShapeFactory1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part1.HybridShapeFactory")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim hybridShapeDirection1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set hybridShapeDirection1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewDirectionByCoord(1#, 2#, 3#)")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim hybridBodies1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set hybridBodies1 = part1.HybridBodies")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim hybridBody1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set hybridBody1 = hybridBodies1.Item(" & Chr(34) & "PointSetx" & Chr(34) & ")")
        sw.WriteLine("dim skteches1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set sketches1 = hybridBody1.HybridSketches")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim sketch1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set sketch1 = sketches1.Item(" & Chr(34) & "Sketch.1" & Chr(34) & ")")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim reference1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set reference1 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(sketch1)")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim hybridShapeExtremum1")
        sw.WriteLine("Set hybridShapeExtremum1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewExtremum(reference1, hybridShapeDirection1, 1)")
        sw.WriteLine("hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape hybridShapeExtremum1")
        sw.WriteLine("Dim reference2")

        Dim lessOneCount As String
        Dim spacing As Double = 0
        Dim count As String
        Dim setString As String
        'loop
```

THIS IS THE PART OF THE CODE THAT IS ADDING EXTRA SPACES

```
For i = 1 To numbOfPoints Step 1

            count = Str(i)
            count.Replace(" ", "")
            MsgBox(count)
            If i < 2 Then
                lessOneCount = "hybridShapeExtremum1"
            Else
                lessOneCount = "HybridShapePointOnCurve" + Str(i - 1)
            End If

            sw.WriteLine("reference2 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(" + lessOneCount + ")")

            setString = "Dim hybridShapePointOnCurve" + count
            sw.WriteLine(setString)
            setString = "hybridShapePointOnCurve" + count + " = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewPointOnCurveWithReferenceFromDistance(reference1, reference2, spacing, False)"
            sw.WriteLine(setString)
            setString = "hybridShapePointOnCurve" + count + ".DistanceType = 1"
            sw.WriteLine(setString)
            setString = "hybridBody1.AppendHybridShape(hybridShapePointOnCurve" + count + ")"
            sw.WriteLine(setString)


        Next

        sw.WriteLine("End Sub")


        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
    End If
```

Sample output:
Dim hybridShapePointOnCurve 2

SHOULD be:
Dim hybridShapePointOnCurve2

What modifications should I make to the way I join strings?

Thanks!

Comment: `count.Replace(" ", "")` isn't doing what you think it is.  The function returns a string - so you would need to do `count = count.Replace(" ", "")` for it to work correctly.

Comment: Just swapped that out, still not working. I only added that as a last resort anyways. str(i) shouldn't give any spaces to begin with.

Comment: You can use the `trim()` method to trim empty spaces instead. So instead of `count.Replace(" ", "")` you can do `count = trim(count)`. Same for your `lessOneCount = "HybridShapePointOnCurve" + Str(i - 1)` use `lessOneCount = "HybridShapePointOnCurve" + trim(Str(i - 1))`

Comment: trim worked for some of the strings. This is still giving an extra space.
    lessOneCount = Trim(lessOneCount)

sw.WriteLine("reference2 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(" + lessOneCount + ")")

Comment: You need to use your debugger to step through your program looking at your variables to determine where your errant space is coming from, VB does not pull them out of clear air.

Comment: @PeterBeamish you're suppose to trim the `Str(i - 1)` to be `trim(Str(i-1))` and not the `lessOneCount` variable. trim doesn't trim the spaces in between the line, it only trim the starting and ending of the Strings if it's spaces, asterisk or apostrophe. Trimming `lessOneCount` is no use as when the String is being Concat, the spaces is in between the characters which result it not being trimed

Answer (score 0):

Realized my comment didn't answer your question completely, so a few things:

1. The `String.Replace` method doesn't work like you think it does.  Saying `count.Replace(" ", "")` doesn't actually change the variable `count`; the function actually returns a new string. For it work like you want, you would need to do `count = count.Replace(" ", "")`.
2. Consider using a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of concatenating a bunch of strings together.  It will greatly improve performance.  When using the `StringBuilder` class, you also wouldn't need to write to the `StreamWriter` until the very end, simply by calling `sw.Write(stringBuilderObject.ToString())`
3. I haven't used VB.NET in a while, but I would check what `Str(i)` returns.  Instead of using VB functions, consider using .NET functions by saying `count = i.ToString()`.  According to Sky, the Str function indeed returns a space because it reserves it for the negative sign.  Based on this, I would use the `.ToString()` method instead.

Comment: The issue with ops is actually Str(i), it will return " 1", " 2" and so. There is a space because it's reserved for a negative sign. That's what the method is returning. He could just trim the spaces or use ToString method as you suggested

Comment: If that's the case, then he should definitely use `i.ToString()` and `(i - 1).ToString()`

Comment: Yes, if he just want to use `Str` function then he will need to trim the empty spaces in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to quickly in my comment, the [`Str`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6a1sx7%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function reserves room for the sign, since it is a positive number there is no sign, if it was negative there would be a minus sign there.  Try `Trim(Str(i))` instead

From above link(*emphasis mine*):

> This example uses the Str function to return a String representation of a number. When a positive number is converted to a string, a leading space is **always reserved for its sign**.